# csv-parser cannot read or open such .csv file

Tags: node.js, csv-parser

csv file is
[image]

and in my index.js
here is my code :

```
    const fs = require('fs');
const csv = require('csv-parser');
const inputFile = "./data.csv"
let results = []

fs.createReadStream(inputFile)
  .pipe(csv())
  .on('data', (data) => results.push(data))
  .on('end', () => {
    console.log(results);
  });
```

why am i getting an error: that no such file or directory './data.csv'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When specifying file paths in node, generally relative paths are derived from the working directory from where node itself was executed. This means if you execute

`node ./backEnd/index.js`

The actual working directory is whatever directory is above `backEnd`. You can see this via `console.log(process.cwd())`.

If you would like to read a file relative to the current file that is being executed, you can do:

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const csv = require('csv-parser');

const inputFile = path.resolve(__dirname, "./data.csv");
let results = []

fs.createReadStream(inputFile)
  .pipe(csv())
  .on('data', (data) => results.push(data))
  .on('end', () => {
    console.log(results);
  });
```

Specifically `__dirname` will always resolve to the directory of the javascript file  being executed. Using `path.resolve` is technically optional here, you could manually put the path together, however using resolve is a better practice.